# How new line affect print in awk?

Tags: awk

The normal format of awk is as below.

```
echo "haha" |awk '{print 6}'
6
```

Now to add a new line after print,other is same as above.

```
echo "haha" |awk '{print
> 6}'
haha
```

How awk interpret the second command?
Does awk read over all the command before interpreting it?

Answer (score 3):

From https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Statements_002fLines.html#FOOT9

Unless the newline is escaped (with a `\`) or it follows one of

```
,    {    ?    :    ||    &&    do    else
```

> A newline at any other point is considered the end of the statement

So your script would be equivalent to:

```
$ echo "haha" |awk '{print;6}'
haha
```

To escape:

```
$ echo "haha" |awk '{print \
6}'
6
```